# How to extract multiple numbers between a repeating pattern using stringr?

Tags: r, stringr

I have a column of strings that look like the string below, where the numbers following the double colons `"::"` are ages. In this example, 51, 40, 9, 5, 2, and 15 are the ages. The numbers following the `"||"` are just saying this is the first person, second person, etc. I'd like to extract just the ages.

```
library(tidyverse)

ex_str = "0::51||1::40||2::9||3::5||4::2||5::15"
```

I've tried things like,

```
test_string |>
  str_extract_all("::[0-9]+")
```

only to get the output below.

```
[[1]]
[1] "::51" "::40" "::9"  "::5"  "::2"  "::15"
```

I apologize for the simple question. I've watched a few videos and read some guides online, but I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`str_extract_all`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringr/versions/0.6.2/topics/str_extract_all) with a regex that includes a positive look-behind for `'::'`:

```
library(tidyverse)

ex_str <- "0::51||1::40||2::9||3::5||4::2||5::15"
ages <- str_extract_all(ex_str, "(?<=::)\\d+") %>% unlist()
ages_numeric <- as.numeric(ages)
print(ages_numeric)
```

**Output:**

```
[1] 51 40  9  5  2 15
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try using `strsplit` on the "||" and then `gsub` out the first digit(s) and the "::":

```
gsub("\\d+::", "",strsplit(ex_str, "\\|\\|")[[1]])

# or (thanks to @r2evans):
gsub("\\d+::", "",strsplit(ex_str, "||", fixed=TRUE)[[1]])
```

You could also so the reverse - `strsplit` after the `gsub`:

```
strsplit(gsub("\\d+::", "",ex_str), "\\|\\|")[[1]]

# or (thanks to @r2evans):
strsplit(gsub("\\d+::", "",ex_str), "||", fixed = TRUE)[[1]]
```

All return the same:

```
#[1] "51" "40" "9"  "5"  "2"  "15"
```

Comment: @r2evans thanks! I edited to add this in approach in (I always forget about `fixed`) - I'm also a fan of not using regex, I often get too lost too easily!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strsplit` like below

```
> strsplit(ex_str, "\\D+")[[1]][c(FALSE, TRUE)]
[1] "51" "40" "9"  "5"  "2"  "15"
```